# How to send POST request from Android to Elasticsearch

Tags: android, json, elasticsearch, android-volley

I have an app, where the 'Feedback' entered by the user is stored as JSONObject. How do I send this JSONObject to elasticsearch?

Below is the code I have tried:

```
     void sendFeedback() {
            String url = "http://localhost:9200/trial_feedback_index2/trial_feedback_type2 ";

/* "trial_feedback_index2" is my index and "trial_feedback_type2" is my type, where I want to store the data,  in elasticsearch.*/

            JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Log.d("Response", response.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            },
                    new Response.ErrorListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            // error
                            // Log.d("Error.Response", response);
                        }
                    }
            ) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams()
                {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Feedback", feedbackQAJsonObjOuter.toString());


                    return params;
                }
            };
            queue.add(postRequest);
    // add it to the RequestQueue


        }
```

How do I make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: `http://localhost:9200/` will not work. That needs to be the external IP of your server, but you've given localhost of your Android device, not running Elasticsearch

Comment: What is the problem? What errors did you get? It's difficult trying to help someone when you don't know what's their exact problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HashMap` to store your data and then convert it to `JSONObject`. After that pass that `JSONObject` to request:

```
HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put("feedbackKey","value");
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(hashMap);

JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
            {..... 
..... Your other code
```